# The trend toward "_field = field;" against "this.field = field"

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have seen that the majority of well-known developers (such as those in Lynda, Pluralsight, etc. or even writers) nowadays prefer the following approach over the latter one:

```
private IField _Field;
publc MyClass (IField Field){
    _Field = Field;
}
```

Over this approach:

```
private IField Field;
public MyClass(IField Field){
    this.Field = Field;
}
```

I know that there must be a reason behind this, but I can't figure out why.

Since this trend has began by the time C# 6 was released, I guess the reason might be due to something relating to Roslyn compiler but could not find anything over Google.

I'd appreciate if anyone could elaborate what advantages the first approach may possibly have over the second one.

Comment: I always thought it was personal preference... But I'd be interested to hear any evidence for leaning towards either approach.

Comment: What's the default style for ReSharper? I bet that has a significant impact on people's behaviour...

Comment: Sorry, was about to edit your post, since your code examples contains errors, but I don't know what to edit them to? No one I've ever seen in C# would name a field "_Field" but rather "_field". Same with parameters... Field -> field.

Comment: Say you're at the bottom of a 1k line piece of code, and you see `this.field` - can you tell at a glance whether that's public or private or not? How about `this._field`? That's the argument I'd make for it (although I'm not sure if that's enough to sell me on it). I tend to prefer being explicit about `this` either way, though.

Comment: It's merely stylistic.  Personally, I hate using `this` and would rather the fields just be named distinctly from variables, so I've always done something similar to the supposed "new way".

Comment: Nope. Nothing related with the compiler. Just personal preferences. Actually I moved from `_field` to `this.field` recently (after adding nice colorizer to VS). Because you will get ugly `_` everywhere, but `this.` you usually will have in constructor only

Comment: In either case, shouldn't the constructor parameter be camel cased?

Comment: @JoeClay: you are right about the `Private Field Concept`!! Very nice idea!!

Comment: I tend to think that prefixing with underscore is (a) ugly, (b) over-reliant on a convention that *could* be broken, and (c) akin to "Hungarian" notation. I'm disappointed if it's making a comeback.

Comment: One other convention I've seen quite frequently - `Field` for public, `field` for private, `_field` for the backing variable for a property. That's what I tend to lean towards, as it makes the IntelliSense a lot less cluttered (backing fields only show up if you actually type an underscore).

Comment: @JoeClay: Thanks Joe, your comments have been very very helpful.

Comment: @cwap: it is very much personal preference - looking at the C# code here there are many examples akin to _Field backing a property called Field - typically the case of the field & property are matching.

Comment: I think the only hard piece of advice I'd give is - pick one that makes sense to you, and then *stick to it throughout your project*. If you're not consistent, it's just going to make your code impossible to understand.

Comment: @JoeClay: If I encountered `this.field` after x KLOC, I would immediately assume that it's a private field, due to the lower-case first letter `f`. If one follows the usual .NET naming conventions, it is a rather rare thing to make anything wih a lower-case initial letter public, especially so fields (which are usually hidden behind properties). It is also rare to have lower-cased properties. So if following the usual conventions, the `_` won't tell you anything that the lower-case initial letter wouldn't tell you already.

Comment: @stakx: That's a good point - probably shows how long it's been since I've seriously written C#...

Comment: I'd add that the `this` notation helps to distinguish static properties. Using `this`, you'll write either `this.Property` or `Property`, depending on whether it's static or not. Using `_`, you'd write `Property` in both cases (unless you mix both `_` and `this`, but I've never seen that)

Comment: It's important to visually distinguish fields from other stuff (like locals) and I personally don't like to write `this.` every time for it, so using underscore. Not to mention it is too easy to forgret 'this' but you cannot forget underscore.

Comment: When I arrived at my current employer, I had a certain naming convention that I used.  Their naming convention was different and, after some time acclimating to it, I now use their naming convention whenever I code.  It is simply a preference issue.  Currently, they/I use "private object _MyObject", "public object MyObject", and "public MyClass(object myObject)". Basically, parameters and local variables start with lower case, private members start with underscore upper case, and public properties start with upper case.

Answer (score 2):

It is just one naming convention - a lot of people coming from C and C++ backgrounds are used to this convention, as it makes it very clear that a field is a field, which is not as easily visible in those languages (given the IDEs that existed when they were invented).

With C# and particularly Visual Studio giving one a lot of help with idenifying members and their scope, this is less needed.

Comment: It's not easy to determine whether an identifier refers to a member variable in C++? How so? You need to elaborate on that. Even more so for C, since C doesn't have classes

Comment: @UnholySheep - my point is that this convention originated in those languages, in order to visually differentiate fields from locals, parameters etc...

Comment: Might have something to do with JavaScript becoming more popular too - since that language doesn't have accessibility modifiers, a lot of people use the leading underscore convention to denote something being private.

Comment: @JoeClay - not seen much of that convention in JavaScript, either seen on sites or in libraries.